# Get row and column number of first cell in Excel table

Tags: vba, excel

I use a lot of tables in my code 
My table is somewhere in my worksheet.
I know I can go to the first cell with the following code:

```
Worksheets("sheet").ListObjects("table").Range.Cells(1, 1).Activate
```

But I would like to store the row and column number in 2 integers ie. column = 3 and row = 4 if first cell of table is C4.

```
Worksheets("sheet").ListObjects("table").Row and Column are not working unfortunately
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This prints the row and the column of the first cell of the table:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")
    Debug.Print tbl.Range.Cells(1, 1).Row
    Debug.Print tbl.Range.Cells(1, 1).Column

    'As a bonus:
    Debug.Print tbl.Range.Rows.Count        'total number of rows
    Debug.Print tbl.Range.Columns.Count     'total number of columns

End Sub
```

---

**Very dirty** way, using your code, which is activating the Cells(1,1):

```
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Row
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Column
```

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly there. You need:

```
Worksheets("sheet").ListObjects("table").Range.Cells(1, 1).Row
```

... to return the absolute row number within the spreadsheet, of your table's first row.

Obviously, the same syntax to return the column number.

Comment: Isn't that going to be the top-left header cell? Shouldn't [DataBodyRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-databodyrange-property-excel) at least be mentioned?